# bind(this) inside recursive IIFE - what is it exactly doing?

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, bind, iife

I have an Object with one property and one method. The method contains a recursive IIFE with a default parameter, that should update with some delay the objects property every time its invoked. To make sure it does so correctly, i bind the IIFE to the property and the index (which functions as a counter) with bind(this). But i am not absolutely sure what bind(this) inside my code is actually doing ...

```
myObj = {

  myArr: [], 

  myMethod: function (myData = [0,1,2,3]) {

    (function recIIFE(index = 0) {
      console.log(index);
      this.myArr[0] = myData[index];
      console.log(this.myArr);
      index < myData.length - 1
      ? setTimeout(recIIFE.bind(this), 3000, index += 1) // First bind(this)
      : setTimeout(recIIFE.bind(this), 3000, index = 0);
    }).bind(this)(); // Second bind(this)
  }
}

myObj.myMethod();
```

So the Output is, that myArr is set to [0], after 3sec [1], 3secs [2], 3secs [3] and then repeats itself ([0], ...).

But my Question concerns the why its working this way, more specific what does bind(this) do here to make it work the way it does.

1) First bind(this) inside the setTimeout:
as i understand it here the bind(this) creates a new Function wrapping the IIFE and passes the context of the IIFE to this new Function. As the context includes the scope of myObj this is always set to the scope of myObj when the IIFE is invoked.

2) Second bind(this):
I am really not sure why its assuring that the correct index is passed every time the IIFE is invoked ...

It would be great if someone can explain in detail what exactly is going on and why its working the way it does. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `.bind(this)()` really should be just `.call(this)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this all involves `.bind()` calls is that without that, the calls to that `recIIFE()` function would not have `this` set to `myObj`.

The initial call to the "recursive" function (it's not really recursive but I'll let that slide for now) is the one labelled in the comment as the "Second" one. That outer `.bind(this)()` creates the first bound version of the function, and it's bound the the value of `this` in `myMethod()`, which is that outer object `myObj`.

Now, in that first call to `recIIFE()`, no parameter is passed so the default value of 0 is used. That sets `myArr` to `[0]`.

The `setTimeout()` calls are next. Inside `recIIFE()`, the function name ("recIIFE") still refers to the *pre-bound* function; in other words, *not* the function created and immediately invoked from `myMethod()`, but the original one. Thus it has to be bound again for the timer invocation to work properly. The value of `this` is still `myObj`, so that's straightforward.

Finally the decision around how to call `setTimeout()` is just a matter of checking the index compared to the value array length so that it starts over at the first element after exhausting all the rest.

---

The reason `recIIFE()` is not really recursive is that at any given time there is only one activation of the function running. There's never a stack of calls-within-calls. That's not really much of an issue unless you care a lot about terminology.